# mysql join with multiple conditions (not OR but AND)

Tags: mysql, join, multiple-conditions

i have problem with join table and use multiple conditions...
My code:

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT sid, MAX(info_date_add) AS max_info_date_add FROM skiresort GROUP BY sid) skiresort_max 
INNER JOIN skiresort 
   ON 
      skiresort_max.sid = skiresort.sid AND 
      skiresort_max.max_info_date_add = skiresort.info_date_add 
JOIN skiresort_theme_value 
   ON skiresort_theme_value.skiresort_id = skiresort.id 
WHERE 
   skiresort_theme_value.skiresort_theme_id = '1' AND 
   skiresort_theme_value.skiresort_theme_id = '2' AND 
   skiresort_theme_value.skiresort_theme_id = '4' 
GROUP BY skiresort.sid 
ORDER BY skiresort.title_en
```

In this code, the conditions are in WHERE clausule. I also tried to put in into JOIN ON (...) but it also didn't work.
When i have only one condition it works. I read some articles about using OR instead of AND, it worked but not as i expected. I need to search only rows with certain IDs (multiple).

Comment: Why in the heck would you use `AND` here and not `OR`. I don't understand what you're trying to do. You want rows where the `skiresort_theme_id` is 1, 2, and 4, *simultaneously*??

Comment: yes like you wrote - simultaneously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not use this instead of many conditions.

```
WHERE 
         skiresort_theme_value.skiresort_theme_id in (1, 2,4) 

GROUP BY skiresort.sid

HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT skiresort_theme_value.skiresort_theme_id) = 3
ORDER BY skiresort.title_en
```

Comment: thanks this solution is working ;) it's little bit slow (i don't know if there is some faster solutions) ANYWAY THANK YOU...

Comment: @general666 this is slow because your computer is old :) . i think its slow because you using group by two times with same column , try remove first one.

Comment: funny if you call macbook pro retina old one :)
it's not working without first group by, select is few times longer i only put here the important part...

Answer (score 0):

when add condition to WHERE, condition must be from FROM tbl
add condition JOIN ON
Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT sid, MAX(info_date_add) AS max_info_date_add FROM skiresort GROUP BY sid) skiresort_max 
INNER JOIN skiresort 
   ON 
      skiresort_max.sid = skiresort.sid AND 
      skiresort_max.max_info_date_add = skiresort.info_date_add 
JOIN skiresort_theme_value 
   ON (skiresort_theme_value.skiresort_id = skiresort.id AND skiresort_theme_value.skiresort_theme_id = '1' AND skiresort_theme_value.skiresort_theme_id = '2' AND skiresort_theme_value.skiresort_theme_id = '4')
GROUP BY skiresort.sid 
ORDER BY skiresort.title_en
```